# Wordpress List all php files involved in page creation

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin which utilizes the MVC design structure. Depending on which URL is being viewed, different controllers are being used to display the desired content.

I am currently trying to modify the content a specific controller is loading, as I am trying to make additional URLs display the same content.

As I am having difficulties finding the according controller handling the requests, I was wondering if there is a way to list all PHP files which are involved in creating a wordpress page.

E.g. When i go to example.com/critical-page is there a way to have all PHP files involved "var_dumped" at the beginning of the page?

That way it would be easier to track which one of the 10000 files are actually involved in the page creation.

Or is there a different way to accomplish what I want to do? Basically tracking the way PHP goes to create the page?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the [XDebug's Profiler](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) tools. Although primarily intended for speed optimization it does give a list of all functions called along with the total cpu time used by the function call.